# AWS CDK with Localstack still detects differences even after deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, localstack

I'm running CDK against Localstack, using [cdklocal](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/integrations/aws-cdk/). I have this Typescript code using CDK lib:

```
const defaultVpc = Vpc.fromLookup(this, 'defaultVpc', {
  region: 'us-east-1',
  isDefault: true
});

const webserver = new Instance(this, 'webserver', {
  instanceType: new InstanceType('t2.micro'),
  machineImage: new AmazonLinuxImage(),
  vpc: defaultVpc,
});
```

I run `cdklocal deploy` and it creates the EC2 instance. But if I run `cdklocal diff`, it still says there are things to do. Why?

```
$ cdklocal diff 
Stack CdkStack
IAM Statement Changes
┌───┬───────────────────────────────┬────────┬────────────────┬───────────────────────────┬───────────┐
│   │ Resource                      │ Effect │ Action         │ Principal                 │ Condition │
├───┼───────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼───────────┤
│ + │ ${webserver/InstanceRole.Arn} │ Allow  │ sts:AssumeRole │ Service:ec2.amazonaws.com │           │
└───┴───────────────────────────────┴────────┴────────────────┴───────────────────────────┴───────────┘
Security Group Changes
┌───┬────────────────────────────────────────────┬─────┬────────────┬─────────────────┐
│   │ Group                                      │ Dir │ Protocol   │ Peer            │
├───┼────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────┼────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ + │ ${webserver/InstanceSecurityGroup.GroupId} │ Out │ Everything │ Everyone (IPv4) │
└───┴────────────────────────────────────────────┴─────┴────────────┴─────────────────┘
(NOTE: There may be security-related changes not in this list. See https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/1299)

Parameters
[+] Parameter SsmParameterValue:--aws--service--ami-amazon-linux-latest--amzn-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2:C96584B6-F00A-464E-AD19-53AFF4B05118.Parameter SsmParameterValueawsserviceamiamazonlinuxlatestamznamihvmx8664gp2C96584B6F00A464EAD1953AFF4B05118Parameter: {"Type":"AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>","Default":"/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2"}

Resources
[+] AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup webserver/InstanceSecurityGroup webserverInstanceSecurityGroupDDD6156D 
[+] AWS::IAM::Role webserver/InstanceRole webserverInstanceRoleFA6A27FD 
[+] AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile webserver/InstanceProfile webserverInstanceProfile7B164AF9 
[+] AWS::EC2::Instance webserver webserverEE139216
```